# Why I can't see that last char in array is null terminator?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, null, null-terminated

How can I check that a `char` array is null terminated?

```
char input[80];

fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

for (i = 0; input[i]; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '\0') {
       printf("null!!!"); // never works
    }
}
```

For example, the below code does not print `null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `for` loop condition, you're already checking for the non-0 value of `input[i]`, so the inside `if` is a *dead* condition.

To test, make an infinite loop, check `if` and then, print and `break` out. Something like

```
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '\0') {
       printf("null!!!\n");  // now works
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as `input[i]` is 0 the loop exits, so that print statement is never executed.

Comment: @avasin please **don't**. It makes all the previous answerers appear foolish. I've rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working code, if you are interested :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char input[] = "I am a string !!";
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
        if (input[i] == '\0') {
           printf("null!!!");
           break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>All answers here don't check memory bounds, so you'll definitely run into a segmentation fault.</strike> Still, if an error occurs during `fread`ing, you may have garbage in `input`.

```
char input[80];

fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

for (i = 0; i<80; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '\0') {
        printf("null!!!"); 
    }
}
```

You could also change `if (input[i] == '\0')` to just `if (! input[i])` since `'\0'` (null-terminator) has ASCII value `0`.

Comment: With all due respect, did you read the `fgets()` man page before nominating other answers as faulty? Isn't it indirectly impose the bounds ? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, yes, why? OK, I now see these answers have a `break` after printing.

Comment: `if ( ! input[i])`will be executed also for `0` value, isn't it? (valid char)

Comment: @avasin, `! input[i]` will evaluate to true only if `input[i]` is zero and a null-terminator is `0` in ASCII.